# Rotating a picture box where the cursor is pointing at, for a top down game

Tags: c#, vb.net

The code I made and looked everywhere in the internet for  rotating an image based on mouse movement seems to be problematic. Despite my efforts, the image remains stationary. I suspect there might be issues with the transformation order, improper use of width and height, or perhaps a missing step. I'm seeking guidance on identifying and rectifying these errors.

In a top-down game, imagine a spaceship represented by an image (picJoueur). The goal is to rotate the spaceship towards the position of the mouse cursor within the game window. However, despite implementing code found online, the spaceship doesn't respond to mouse movement as expected.

For instance, when the mouse cursor is at the top-left corner of the game window, the spaceship should rotate precisely to face that direction. Unfortunately, the spaceship remains fixed and doesn't align with the cursor. The suspicion is that there are errors in the transformation logic, potential issues with width and height calculations, or a missing step in the code.

Seeking assistance to pinpoint and rectify these errors, I'm open to any guidance or insights. Thank you for your help!

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5vTT.png)[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DB6I.png)

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        opp = e.Y - picJoueur.Top - picJoueur.Height / 2;
        adj = e.X - picJoueur.Left - picJoueur.Width / 2;

        double angle = (Math.Atan2(opp, adj)) * (180 / Math.PI);

        Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(picJoueur.Image.Width, picJoueur.Image.Height);

        g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);

        

        g.TranslateTransform((float)picJoueur.Image.Height / 2, (float)picJoueur.Image.Width / 2);
        g.ScaleTransform((float)0.5, (float)0.5);
        g.RotateTransform((float)angle);
        g.TranslateTransform(-((float)picJoueur.Image.Height / 2), -((float)picJoueur.Image.Width / 2));
        g.DrawImage(picJoueur.Image, new Point(0,0));



    }
```